# Intersection between name lists with Variant () type variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have basic level with VBA and need to put together a distinct list of names based on two other lists. Each of them comes from a named range in Excel. With the code below, I can test if the element is present in a list and if it is unique, at least I think it is correct. However, I can't assemble the same structure for the new list because the name becomes a single String. What would be the correct way to add a new String as a list element?

```
Dim list1 As Variant
Dim list2 As Variant
Dim list3 As Variant

list1 = [rngDistinctNames]
list2 = [rngAllNames]

Dim name As Variant
For Each name In list1
     result = Application.Match(name, list2, 0)
     If Not IsError(result) Then
        result = Application.Match(name, list3, 0)
        If IsError(result) Then
            list3 = list3 + name
        End If
     End If
Next name
```

Comment: `list3 = list3 + name` what are your trying to achieve here? A concatenated string? I'm not sure but don't you just want all unique values from both `list1` and `list2`? One way is to look into `RemoveDuplicates`. Or do you only want results from `list1` if they are NOT in `list2`? In that case you can load one `List2` into an dictionary or arraylist and check if values exists

Comment: Thanks for that, @JvdV. I would like to continue working with a Variant array because I can't change my sheet - this code I exemplified is an ancillary part of broader logic. Actually, I don't want to concatenate the String. I need a third list with the same structure as the first two. Each string must be an element in list3 [Variant () type]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Dictionary` object and take its `Keys()` into variant array:

```
Dim list1 As Variant
Dim list2 As Variant
Dim list3 As Variant

list1 = [rngDistinctNames]
list2 = [rngAllNames]

Dim name As Variant
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'instantiate and reference a Dictionary object
    For Each name In list1 ' loop through list1 names
         If Not IsError(Application.Match(name, list2, 0)) Then .Item(name) = 1 ' if current list1 name is in list2 then add it to dictionary keys (if already there it'll be simply overwritten by itself
    Next
    list3 = .keys ' take dictionary keys list3 array
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I didn't quite understand how it worked, but it was exactly what I needed.

Comment: You are welcome. It works using `Dictionary` object which by its "constitution" accepts only unique keys: you'd better search for some documentation online

Comment: I will search. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine the following data:

[image]

- `A2:A8` = named range `rngDistinctNames`
- `B2:B5` = named range `rngAllNames`

So now with the following code we can check each value in the first named range against the second:

```
Sub Test()

Dim list1 As Variant, list2 As Variant
Dim list3 As Object: Set list3 = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Dim i As Long

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName to avoid implicit references

    'Put named ranges into array (memory) for fast looping
    list1 = [rngDistinctNames]
    list2 = [rngAllNames]

    'Put list1 into an ArrayList
    For x = LBound(list1) To UBound(list1)
        list3.Add list1(x, 1)
    Next x

    'Check list2 against arraylist and delete values if need be
    For x = LBound(list2) To UBound(list2)
        list3.Remove list2(x, 1)
    Next x

    'Additional, write remaining values from list3
    .Range("C2").Resize(list3.Count) = Application.Transpose(list3.ToArray)

End With

End Sub
```

This will result in:

[image]

`ArrayList` is just one of the options you can try. Additionally you could look into `Collection` and `Dictionary` but I like to use `ArrayList` because you can check `list2` values and remove them even if not present in the `ArrayList` plus you can write it directly into an array and use that somewhere in your sheet with `.ToArray`.

As per your comment, if you want an `Array` of `Variant/Data Type` values, you just have to use that same property: `array = List3.ToArray` will return just that :)